# MultipartFile to BufferedImage

Tags: java, spring, backend

Can I convert `MultipartFile` from the library (`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`) to a `BufferedImage` without first saving it to the local disk? If yes, please tell me how to do it

I used to save to disk and then get a BufferedImage from there, but now I need to do it without saving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the following?

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(multipartFile.getInputStream())
```